# Dynamic object, persistable to Azure and Querable by Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic, azure

what I'm trying to do is create a Dynamic Contact list.
I'm using Azure SQL storage for persisting my data, and EF.

The typed **base class "Contact"** hass props like Id, Name, Phone
and a **"Profile" class,** that has props like ContactId, PropName, PropVal to enable storage of unlimited number of Contact attributes (like Sex, Address, Age, ect..).

[image: EF Model]

So now, this works :

```
var cts = db.Contacts
            .Where(p => p.ContactProfile.Any(pr => pr.PropertyName == "Sex" && pr.ValueString == "F")
            && p.ContactProfile.Any(pr => pr.PropertyName == "City" && pr.ValueString == "Kaunas"));
```

What I'm hoping to achieve - is create a dynamic POCO class, that would map to the described EF structure, and enable querying those dynamic properties with Linq or (*Dynamic Linq).
What I've managed to achieve is create that Dynamic class using this "[Expando](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Feb/08/Creating-a-dynamic-extensible-C-Expando-Object)" implementation of dynamic class.

So I'm able to map EF model to Expando like this

```
var contact = db.Contacts.First();    
dynamic dynContact = new Expando();
dynContact["Sex"] = db.ContactProfiles.First(p => p.Contact.Id == contact.Id && p.PropertyName == "Sex").ValueString;
dynContact.City = db.ContactProfiles.First(p => p.Contact.Id == contact.Id && p.PropertyName == "City").ValueString;
```

I **can't figure out** how to make this work :
(so it would result in the same SQL query as the first Linq query)

```
DynamicContact.Where(p=>p["Sex"] = "F" && p.City = "NY")
```

Comment: I suspect that what you ultimately want is something like this 

var cts = db.Contacts
            .Where(p => p.Sex  == "F")
            && p.City == "Kaunas");

That would be a non-trivial to implement and would require building a LINQ provider and translating to the correct underlying SQL. This link may be helpful. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx

Comment: Yep, I'm almost at the same conclusion, that a QueryProvider is the answer to this. That would intercept the query, and transform it as needed. 

I think Linq-to-Entities does basically the same thing.

Comment: Well, so far we're leaning towards a "dynamic SQL proc" solution, that builds up a query inside, based on some param values passed in. It seems that CTE queries are much more efficient than the EXISTs, and in this case performance is a factor.. Too bad that LINQ of EF doesn't support CTE queries :(

Answer (score 0):

Rob Connery did something very similar in his project called [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive/).  It may do exactly what you are trying to do, or give you the missing pieces to the puzzle.

Comment: It seems that it might be a possible solution in another situation.